# React native push notification with remote image

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, push, react-native-push-notification

I am using [react-native-push-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification) to send remote push notification to android and ios devices. I am able to receive notifications perfectly.

Now I want to show images in push notifications. I tried using `largeIcon: "ic_launcher"` in payload in localNotification. It is working fine, but when  I try to give a remote image url like `largeIcon: "http://example.com/some_remote_image.jpg"` then it is not showing the image in notification.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.